# Can $f([x])$ be continuous?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

There is a problem I encountered which has two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that $g(f(x))=x$ and $f(\lfloor g(x) \rfloor)=x, \quad \forall x\geq 0$. I am not giving any other details here, because what I want to know is how it is possible that $f(\lfloor x \rfloor)=x$? All I know by graphical transformation of $f(x)\to f(\lfloor x \rfloor)$ that the graph obtained is piecewise, not continuous. So how is this case possible?
One situation I could think of is $f(x)=x, x \in \mathbf Z$. But here, the domain is $\mathbf R$. I would like to know other simple cases when it could be possible, so that it won't be hard for me to imagine such a function.

**Edit**
Here is the complete definition of function:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\sqrt{1-x^2},& -1\leq x < 0\\
x^2+1,& 0\leq x < 1\\
\frac{(x-1)^2)}{4} +2, & x\geq 1
\end{cases}
$$
$g(x)$ is defined such that $g(f(x))=x, x \geq -1$ and $f(\lfloor(g(x)\rfloor)= x, x\geq0$

Comment: No such function from $\Bbb R$ into $\Bbb R$ can exist. If it did, then$$0=f\left(\lfloor0\rfloor\right)=f\left(\left\lfloor\frac12\right\rfloor\right)=\frac12.$$

Comment: If $x$ ranges over $\Bbb{Z} + t$ for some $t \in \Bbb{R}$, then you can recover $x$ from $\lfloor x \rfloor$. If $x$ is allowed to take two values in an interval $[i, i  + 1)$ for $i \in \Bbb{Z}$ then $x \mapsto \lfloor x \rfloor $ is not injective.

Comment: There are not such functions since if you set x as f(x) we will have f([x])=x which contradicts with definition of function.

Comment: I feel like the function $g$ itself shouldn't exist... To prevent $f$ from being multi-valued due to $f(\lfloor g(x)\rfloor) = x$, $\lfloor g \rfloor$ would have to be injective from $[0,\infty)$ to $\mathbb{Z}$, but by Cantor-Bernstein that would imply that $\mathbb{Z}$ and $[0,\infty)$ are in bijection, which they aren't...

Comment: I have included the definition of $f(x)$. Maybe $g(x)$ exists somehow, considering the details I added. I can provide the complete problem, if that can help me wrap my head around the existence of $g(x)$.

Comment: I'll try to clarify what I said earlier which still applies now: $g$ doesn't exist because there will be at least two distinct reals $x$ and $y$ satisfying $\lfloor g(x) \rfloor = \lfloor g(y) \rfloor$, otherwise $\lfloor g \rfloor : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{Z}$ would be injective, but the Cantor-Bernstein theorem tells us that if we have two sets $E$ and $F$ such that there exists an injection from $E$ to $F$ and an injection from $F$ to $E$, then there exists a bijection from $E$ to $F$. We already have that $x \in \mathbb{N} \mapsto x \in [0, +\infty)$ is injective, and... (1/2)

Comment: ...$\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ are in bijection, thus there is an injection from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $[0,\infty)$, meaning that $[0,+\infty)$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ would be in bijection, which is absurd since $\mathbb{Z}$ is countable and $[0, \infty)$ isn't. Thus $\lfloor g \rfloor$ cannot be injective. But, what that entails is that, going back to $x$ and $y$, $x = f(\lfloor g(x)\rfloor) = f(\lfloor g(y) \rfloor) = y$, contradiction, hence $g$ cannot exist. (2/2)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Bruno ! I get it much better now. Probably there is a mistake in my textbook, since it uses $[x]$ (Greatest Integer Function) instead of $\lfloor x \rfloor$ (Floor function), but I m assured now that $f(\lfloor g(x)\rfloor)=x$ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a $g$ can't exist. Indeed, $S = \mathrm{Im}(x \mapsto f(\lfloor g(x) \rfloor)) \subset f(\mathbb{Z})$ because $\lfloor g \rfloor$ has value in $\mathbb{Z}$. The set $S$ is at most countable because $\mathbb{Z}$ is (whatever are $f$ and $g$, continuous or not). However, the image of the identity function is the whole $\mathbb{R}$, which is uncoutable.

With the same argument, you can prove that if $f(\lfloor g \rfloor)$ is continuous on a connected space, then its image is an interval, thus it is either uncountable either a point, and this image is at most countable (once more with no hypothesis on $f$ and $g$). It proves that in this case, $f(\lfloor g \rfloor)$ is constant.

Comment: I am having trouble following your argument in second paragraph. I am good with the first argument, though. Although I understood Bruno's comment, and my query is resolved, but I would like you to elaborate a bit more.

Comment: Let $I$ be the set of definition of $h = f(\lfloor g \rfloor)$ and assume it to be an interval. Then, if $h$ is continuous, its image is an interval $J$ by the intermediate value theorem. However, any interval with a non-empty interior is uncountable (thus we can not find a surjection $\mathbb{Z} \twoheadrightarrow J$ and $J \subset f(\mathbb{Z})$). It implies that $J$ is a singleton so $h$ is constant.

Comment: What you said felt like intuitively correct, but I didn't know about the intermediate value theorem before, but I looked it up now. Thanks for the explanation.